# Power source temporarily disconnecting + web forum submission freezes computer

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, dell, power-management, battery

My Sanyo DELL NT3627 battery has a current charge of 3%, says 'Charging' but does not increase, and periodically the laptop behaves as if the power source has been disconnected.

Usually, I can continue what I'm doing during this time -- the screen dims and the OS says the computer's now running on battery power before it recognizes the electricity flowing into it a few moments later -- but when I clicked 'Submit' on a (lengthy) Reddit comment, the computer froze. I tried to move the cursor and clicked and pressed keys, waited five minutes, then unplugged and replugged in the power source, then tried pressing right Alt+Prnt Scrn (SysRq) key + -R, -E, -I, -S, -U, -B. All to no effect, I hard-shut off (via power button hold) and restarted to come here to ask you how to fix these problems.

This Dell Latitude D620 is ~11 years old, purchased off Amazon three months ago; looks clean and new, but the power source is a Chinese AC adapter (with high pitch buzz), not the one designed by Dell. I did not begin using this computer regularly until a few weeks ago; my impression is the battery lasted less than five full charges before beginning this problem of maximizing at 6%. It is not charging in the Windows 7 OS, either. (I have dual-boot Win 7 Pro & lubuntu 16.04.)

Can you help me?

The only solution I can think of is to try to copy my data to USB and reinstall the OS, because I am having other issues: After the first crash described above weeks ago, the trackpad began click-dragging when trying only to move the cursor; AbiWord (first time I've used it just now, trying to use its autosave feature in case of another crash) is slow with flickering screen, suggesting some display driver incompatibility (typing this now on leafpad instead, saving frequently); Terminal frequently says, "/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-dark-panel/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:682: Unable to find include file: "apps/xfce4-notifyd.rc".

Comment: You bought an 11 year old computer?  You need to throw it out and get something that isn't older than dirt in computer terms.  The battery is obviously shot, and probably other components as well.

Comment: You describe multiple issues; its better to talk about only a single one. The first is battery which is EOL from your description and needs replacement. If you use the machine with power only I'd not bother.  If you look at battery store you'll see what it was designed to hold & what its actually holding and I'd expect it to be very low. As for freezing and dimming it sounds like a dirty connector which again is hardware related and not suited for here (it'll take time to inspect and clean your contacts from power-supply thru to battery...)

Comment: psusi, isn't lubuntu supposed to be used for old computers? Is it such a bad idea to buy such old computers if they come with an Amazon guarantee? (Though mine expired; I was busy...) It's been running fast like a new computer (web browsing mainly), except for the trackpad + battery + freezing that started after a few weeks (first freeze when I was watching a DVD while importing songs on USB drive to Rhythmbox). 

guiverc, cleaning connections to the battery sounds like a lot of work ... So do you think it's good to try reinstalling the OS, and if the issues recur, conclude it's hardware?